# How many times compassionate appointment can be given to a family

Tags: india, children

In a family the husband who was a Group-D in **Department of Posts, India** died while in service. His wife claimed compassionate appointment and the Department has appointed the wife under compassionate ground. Subsequently the wife also has died while in service.

Now the question is whether any of the remaining dependent members of the said family is entitled for compassionate appointment if having requisite qualification and fulfilling the financial criteria etc.

Comment: Fascinating question. I've never heard of compassionate appointment before as a formal policy.

Comment: @ohwilleke perhaps if you find the question fascinating you should upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

in india as per rules compassionate appointment to be given to a approved probationer government staff legal-hiers within a 3years period with related [documents](https://deoceo.blogspot.in/2013/04/documents-required-for-compassionate.html)